# How to parse amcharts stock dates

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How can we parse the amcharts stock dates?

Here example datas:

```
chartData1=[{
    'date':'01-09-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'01-10-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'01-11-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'02-07-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'02-11-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'03-07-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':2,
    'volume':2
},{
    'date':'03-08-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':2,
    'volume':2
},{
    'date':'04-08-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
},{
    'date':'04-09-2010,00:05:05',
    'value':1,
    'volume':1
}];
```

When use it like this the dates from and to time period coming from like this:

```
From
29-10-1920
To
30-10-1920
```

How can I fix this error with parsing dates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply set chart.dataDateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY,JJ:NN:SS"

Comment: Are you sure this is true for am STOCK charts? I see this option on normal amCharts, but not in the documentation for amChart Stock (which OP is asking for). Adding `dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",` has no effect in my amChart Stock

Comment: It's in docs: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#dataDateFormat

Comment: If you could show us your chart, we could help. Better address our support directly.

Comment: And if the OP is referencing the PeriodSelector then similarly set `periodSelector.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY,JJ:NN:SS"`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you and the only way I got around this was to use Javascript date objects instead of date strings.

Instead of writing

```
'date':'01-09-2010,00:05:05'
```

I write is as

```
'date': new Date(2010, 09, 01, 00, 05, 05, 00)
```

I looked through the amCharts website for their Stock Chart demos they only use date objects instead of date strings:
http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/your-first-stock-chart/

It looks like the plugin doesn't parse date strings correctly. For regular amCharts it works fine with the chart.dataDateFormat option, but not for the Stock Charts in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the dataformat for the category axis, as per your requirement it is set to following format:

> chart.dataDateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY,JJ:NN:SS"

Then you have to define whether you want to display your data daily, hourly, or every minute. Default setting  is daily, for hourly you can use

> categoryAxesSettings.minPeriod = "hh"

For more details visit https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/formatting-dates/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the date format for the category axis, you also have to set parseDates for category Axis to true if you're using date objects for your categoryAxis.