# How to stack Charts with amchart?

Tags: graph, stack, scrollbar, amcharts

is it possible to stack 2 or more graphs in one chart? with the same Scrollbar / Chartcursor?

I tried it with the live editor, but havn't found any option to make this possible.

Here som pictures for explaination:

At the moment i have this graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLQFm.jpg

But i want a graph like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47fAh.jpg

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you considered using Stock Chart for this? http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/ It supports multiple charts (panels) and are automatically synced with each-other as well as share the same scrollbar. Please note that it's meant for date-based data, so if you're aiming for arbitrary series-based data, Stock Chart might not work.

Comment: Yeah, i did. But had the problem with the time format. I have a timestamp based on milliseconds, and the graph wasn't able to "unterstand" it.

I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745718/how-to-parse-amcharts-stock-dates
But that didn't work for me...
But give me a moment, i recheck this...

Comment: Ok, you are right. I mixes settings from a serial graph with a stock graph.
To enable correct data Format you have to set the following options:

'     categoryAxesSettings: {
      minPeriod: "fff",
      groupToPeriods: ['fff'] // specify period grouping
     },'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the sake of sport I tried to implement it. Good news - it's possible :)

### First of all you will need to prepare both charts

First chart

- Scrollbar enabled
- Chart cursor enabled
- Category axis hidden
- Legend disabled
- Bottom margin: 0

Second chart

- Scrollbar disabled
- Chart cursor enabled
- Category axis enabled
- Legend enabled
- Top margin: 0

This creates two charts, "glued" together like in your mockup:

[image]

### Syncing the charts

They still act on their own, like two separate charts. We have to sync them up:

- Cursor
- Legend
- Zoom/pan

That's where this code comes in:

```
/**
 * Use events to sync up cursors and zooms
 */
for ( var x = 0; x < AmCharts.charts.length; x++ ) {

  // use "changed" event to track cursor movement on all charts
  // place the cursor on other charts on the same index
  AmCharts.charts[ x ].addListener( "changed", function( event ) {

    // find which category is currently being rolled over
    var category = event.chart.dataProvider[ event.index ][ event.chart.categoryField ];

    // cycle through all available charts and place the cursor at
    // the same category
    for ( var i = 0; i < AmCharts.charts.length; i++ ) {
      if ( event.chart !== AmCharts.charts[ i ] ) {
        AmCharts.charts[ i ].chartCursor.showCursorAt( category );
      }
    }

  } );

  // use "zoomed" event to track zooms/pans so we can apply
  // the same zoom across other charts
  AmCharts.charts[ x ].addListener( "zoomed", function( zoomEvent ) {

    // cycle through all available charts and apply same zoom
    for ( var i = 0; i < AmCharts.charts.length; i++ ) {
      if ( zoomEvent.chart !== AmCharts.charts[ i ] && ( AmCharts.charts[ i ].startIndex != zoomEvent.startIndex || AmCharts.charts[ i ].endIndex != zoomEvent.endIndex ) ) {
        AmCharts.charts[ i ].zoomToIndexes( zoomEvent.startIndex, zoomEvent.endIndex );
      }
    }

  } );

}

/**
 * Use the last chart to display legend
 * We will collect graphs from other charts and mirror them on
 * the last chart.
 */
var lastChart = AmCharts.charts[ AmCharts.charts.length - 1 ];
for ( var x = 0; x < ( AmCharts.charts.length - 1 ); x++ ) {

  // add graphs
  for ( var g = 0; g < AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs.length; g++ ) {

    // create the related graph
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.lineColor = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].lineColor;
    graph.relatedGraph = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ];
    graph.valueField = "value_" + x + "_" + g;
    graph.showBalloon = false;
    graph.includeInMinMax = false;
    graph.title = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].title;
    lastChart.addGraph( graph );

    // mirror data for rollovers
    for ( var i = 0; i < lastChart.dataProvider.length; i++ ) {
      lastChart.dataProvider[ i ][ graph.valueField ] = AmCharts.charts[ x ].dataProvider[ i ][ AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].valueField ];
    }

  }

}

/**
 * Add events to the legend of last chart so we can toggle
 * graphs of the other charts
 */
lastChart.addListener( "init", function() {

  // hide graph
  lastChart.legend.addListener( "hideItem", function( event ) {
    if ( event.dataItem.relatedGraph !== undefined ) {
      event.dataItem.relatedGraph.chart.hideGraph( event.dataItem.relatedGraph );
    }
  } );

  // show graph
  lastChart.legend.addListener( "showItem", function( event ) {
    if ( event.dataItem.relatedGraph !== undefined ) {
      event.dataItem.relatedGraph.chart.showGraph( event.dataItem.relatedGraph );
    }
  } );
} );
```

And voila:

[image]

Here's a working demo:

```js
/**
 * First chart
 * With scrollbar
 * Without category axis
 */
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv1", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "category": "Category #1",
    "value": 2025
  }, {
    "category": "Category #2",
    "value": 1882
  }, {
    "category": "Category #3",
    "value": 1809
  }, {
    "category": "Category #4",
    "value": 1322
  }, {
    "category": "Category #5",
    "value": 1122
  }, {
    "category": "Category #6",
    "value": 1114
  }, {
    "category": "Category #7",
    "value": 984
  }, {
    "category": "Category #8",
    "value": 711
  }, {
    "category": "Category #9",
    "value": 665
  }, {
    "category": "Category #10",
    "value": 580
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0,
    "showFirstLabel": false,
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "title": "First graph"
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#f56400",
    "type": "step",
    "valueField": "value",
    "title": "Graph 1"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorColor": "#c30000",
    "animationDuration": 0
  },
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "axisAlpha": 0
  },
  "marginBottom": 0,
  "marginLeft": 80

} );

/**
 * Second chart
 * Without scrollbar
 * With category axis
 */
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "zoomOutText": "",
  "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "category": "Category #1",
    "value": 521
  }, {
    "category": "Category #2",
    "value": 215
  }, {
    "category": "Category #3",
    "value": 655
  }, {
    "category": "Category #4",
    "value": 601
  }, {
    "category": "Category #5",
    "value": 122
  }, {
    "category": "Category #6",
    "value": 114
  }, {
    "category": "Category #7",
    "value": 521
  }, {
    "category": "Category #8",
    "value": 351
  }, {
    "category": "Category #9",
    "value": 222
  }, {
    "category": "Category #10",
    "value": 156
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0,
    "showLastLabel": false,
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "title": "Second graph"
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#fae879",
    "type": "step",
    "valueField": "value",
    "title": "Graph 2"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorColor": "#c30000",
    "animationDuration": 0
  },
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "tickPosition": "middle"
  },
  "legend": {},
  "marginTop": 0,
  "marginLeft": 80

} );

/**
 * Use events to sync up cursors and zooms
 */
for ( var x = 0; x < AmCharts.charts.length; x++ ) {

  // use "changed" event to track cursor movement on all charts
  // place the cursor on other charts on the same index
  AmCharts.charts[ x ].addListener( "changed", function( event ) {
    
    // find which category is currently being rolled over
    var category = event.chart.dataProvider[ event.index ][ event.chart.categoryField ];

    // cycle through all available charts and place the cursor at
    // the same category
    for ( var i = 0; i < AmCharts.charts.length; i++ ) {
      if ( event.chart !== AmCharts.charts[ i ] ) {
        AmCharts.charts[ i ].chartCursor.showCursorAt( category );
      }
    }

  } );

  // use "zoomed" event to track zooms/pans so we can apply
  // the same zoom across other charts
  AmCharts.charts[ x ].addListener( "zoomed", function( zoomEvent ) {

    // cycle through all available charts and apply same zoom
    for ( var i = 0; i < AmCharts.charts.length; i++ ) {
      if ( zoomEvent.chart !== AmCharts.charts[ i ] && ( AmCharts.charts[ i ].startIndex != zoomEvent.startIndex || AmCharts.charts[ i ].endIndex != zoomEvent.endIndex ) ) {
        AmCharts.charts[ i ].zoomToIndexes( zoomEvent.startIndex, zoomEvent.endIndex );
      }
    }

  } );
  
}

/**
 * Use the last chart to display legend
 * We will collect graphs from other charts and mirror them on
 * the last chart.
 */
var lastChart = AmCharts.charts[ AmCharts.charts.length - 1 ];
for ( var x = 0; x < ( AmCharts.charts.length - 1 ); x++ ) {
  
  // add graphs
  for ( var g = 0; g < AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs.length; g++ ) {
    
    // create the related graph
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.lineColor = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].lineColor;
    graph.relatedGraph = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ];
    graph.valueField = "value_" + x + "_" + g;
    graph.showBalloon = false;
    graph.includeInMinMax = false;
    graph.title = AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].title;
    lastChart.addGraph( graph );
    
    // mirror data for rollovers
    for ( var i = 0; i < lastChart.dataProvider.length; i++ ) {
      lastChart.dataProvider[ i ][ graph.valueField ] = AmCharts.charts[ x ].dataProvider[ i ][ AmCharts.charts[ x ].graphs[ g ].valueField ];
    }
    
  }
  
}

/**
 * Add events to the legend of last chart so we can toggle
 * graphs of the other charts
 */
lastChart.addListener( "init", function() {
  
  // hide graph
  lastChart.legend.addListener( "hideItem", function( event ) {
    if ( event.dataItem.relatedGraph !== undefined ) {
      event.dataItem.relatedGraph.chart.hideGraph( event.dataItem.relatedGraph );
    }
  } );
  
  // show graph
  lastChart.legend.addListener( "showItem", function( event ) {
    if ( event.dataItem.relatedGraph !== undefined ) {
      event.dataItem.relatedGraph.chart.showGraph( event.dataItem.relatedGraph );
    }
  } );
} );
```

```css
.chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv1" class="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="chartdiv2" class="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. The only thing that doens't work well is the function to toggle graph on/off.
It just work with the last graph.

Comment: Do you mean if you have more than one graph per chart "panel"?